# Esconder uma coluna da Grid da Kendo UI quando utilizado um cabeçalho de colunas

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Olá,

Tenho uma grid da kendo com várias colunas, todas separadas por cabeçalhos, observe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso da imagem eu preciso esconder dinamicamente a coluna meta do cabeçalho faturamento. Antes dos cabeçalhos eu usava o seguinte código onde "aChk" é o value de uma checkbox:

```
function esconderMostrarColuna(aChk) {
   var grid = $("#grdDados").data("kendoGrid");
   for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
      if (grid.columns[i].field == aChk.value) {
        if (!aChk.checked) {
          grid.hideColumn(i);
        } else {
          grid.showColumn(i);
        }
        return;
      }
   }
}
```

Depois que adicionei o cabeçalho, não estou mais conseguindo fazer o hideColumn de forma correta. Atualmente tenho o meu código assim:

```
function esconderMostrarColuna(aChk) {
  var grid = $("#grdDados").data("kendoGrid");
  for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < grid.columns.length; j++) {
      if(grid.columns[i].columns[j] != undefined){
        if (grid.columns[i].columns[j].field == aChk.value) {
          if (!aChk.checked) {
            grid.hideColumn(i);
          } else {
            grid.showColumn(i);
          }
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela Kendo é possível somente esconder tudo, não tem como esconder só uma das colunas. Portanto ou esconde "Meta" e "Dt/Hr" (O Faturamento inteiro), ou não esconde esta coluna.

Comment: eita.. 4 meses depois..